# Prove or disprove: to any function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$, if $f^{-1}[B]=A$ then $f[A]=B$.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $X,Y$ be sets and $B\subseteq Y, A\subseteq X$ are subsets.
Prove or disprove: to any function $f: X \longrightarrow Y$, if $f^{-1}[B]=A$ then $f[A]=B$.

I think it's false, because you can take $X=A=\{1,2,3\}$ and $Y=B=\{1,2,3,4\}$ with the identity function, but I'm not sure if this example is correct.

Comment: Your example is correct.

Comment: Except that the function is the inclusion, not the identity.

Comment: Also take for instance $f:\Omega\to\mathbb R, \omega\mapsto 0$ for any set $\Omega\neq\emptyset$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each $x \in A$, we have $f(x) \in B$, hence $f^{-1}[B]=A$.

Conclusion: $f^{-1}[B]=A$ holds for each(!) mapping $f:A \to B.$

$f[A]=B$ holds $ \iff f$ is surjective.